# Problem with Growing coleus blumei propagate in water

Tags: growth, propagation

I have one coleus blumei main flower which have had black stem problem.

So i removed the black parts and placed that corrupted part into bobble with water like this:

[image]

[image]

And after almost three-day i have again black stems on them, i have seen some growed coleus blumei flower at water like [this](https://youtu.be/dNH4eYV4JUQ) video and :

[image]

So what fo you think i do know is better?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the water in your area? If It's bad, try some DI deionized, or RO reverse osmosis, or plain old distilled water. Also, when I root Coleus, I trim off more leaves than you. Lacking a root system, those leaves may be sucking more water than the stem can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stems in your image which are successfully rooting in water, you can see they are much thicker, stronger stems than the ones you've been trying. They do root in water, but you need a strongly growing apical stem to make a good cutting to root this way - perhaps you took your cuttings from side shoots.

if the plant you took your cuttings from is not growing strongly yet, wait till it is and then cut an apical stem or two and try those. Further instructions here https://dengarden.com/gardening/How-to-Propagate-Coleus-from-Cuttings